# jQuery ui multiselect catch select/click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I would like to catch the click/change selection event on a listbox that has a jQuery [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) on it.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't catch it.

```
        $("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").multiselect();

        $("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            alert('multiselect clicked');
            $('#' + '<%= divRemoval.ClientID %>').hide();
        });
```

This code is written in $(document).ready

Html code

```
<asp:ListBox ID="_lbxMultiSelect" runat="server" DataTextField="SegmentName"
    DataValueField="SegmentId" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

the following suggestion did not work

```
$("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").bind('click change', function () {
```

What is the right way to catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the event `multiselectclick`

```
$("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").bind('multiselectclick', function (e, ui) {
```

or (in version 1.7 onwards)

```
$('body').on('multiselectclick', "#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>", function(e, ui){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

you should look at the "events" section of the link you posted

Comment: Your are right, just had to read more carefully the documention in the link.
thanks for the solution, its works!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").change(function () {
```

to

```
$("#" + "<%= _lbxMultiSelect.ClientID %>").bind('click change', function () {
```